# With Python and `win32com`, how to open a RTF file without the pop-up asking to convert?

Tags: python, ms-word, pywin32, win32com, rtf

When opening a RTF document in MS Word, Word is usually showing a pop-up to ask for converting (with different format including RTF).

Therefore, when opening the same file with `win32com`, you need to manually click on the icon of MS Word or switch to MS Word if this is open (to show this pop up) and click on **OK**. That breaks the automation flow.

The code I have currently is this one:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from win32com import client, __gen_path__

rtf_file = Path(...)

word = client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open(str(rtf_file.absolute()))
doc.Activate()
```

How to by-pass this pop-up to automate processing of RTF files?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually deactivate alerts and put `False` to first argument of `Open` method, which is `ConfirmConversions`.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from win32com import client, __gen_path__

rtf_file = Path(...)

word = client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
word.DisplayAlerts = True
doc = word.Documents.Open(str(rtf_file.absolute()), False)
doc.Activate()
```

Note: you can see the whole list of arguments with `help(word.Documents.Open)`.